# Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate record not found when searching by email

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I'm using spring version 5.0.8.RELEASE and I am trying to make a search in the database with an email address using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. If I search with the whole address I'm getting no results

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForList("SELECT p.* FROM users p WHERE p.email = :email", new MapSqlParameterSource(){{addValue("email", "a.alexandrakis@company.com")}})
```

if I change the code to this I'm getting one result, as expected

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForList("SELECT p.* FROM users p WHERE p.email like :email", new MapSqlParameterSource(){{addValue("email", "a.alexandrakis@%")}})
```

and if change the code to this I'm getting no results again

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForList("SELECT p.* FROM users p WHERE p.email like :email", new MapSqlParameterSource(){{addValue("email", "a.alexandrakis@c%")}})
```

It seems that something is happening if the @ character is on the string. Do I have to escape it somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try parameter value with "a.alexandrakis'@company.com" or "a.alexandrakis\@company.com"

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Debopam i've try it in sqlserver and mysql too. i 've also try several ways to escape the character but nothing worked so far. I will try yours suggestions too in a while an i will let you know.

Comment: @Debopam none of this worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After all there is no issue... I was looking to another database with similar data.